# Symfony2.7.0 app_dev.php route not found

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-2.7

I am learning symfony2, I have installed symfony2.7.0 LTS using below command.

```
symfony new sflearning
```

and I have installed symfony2.7.0 successfully. Now when I am trying run app_dev.php on localhost using below url,

http://localhost/sflearning/web/app_dev.php
It gives me an error

> No route found for "GET /"

It was working with previous version properly, is it only route issue or there is something missing ? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the AcmeDemoBundle is no longer installed by default with Symfony 2.7.

You should start creating a new bundle, with a controller and a route pointing to "/".

You can also visit http://localhost/sflearning/web/app_dev.php/app/example as a default controller is created in a default "AppBundle" installed with Symfony.

Or if you want to see a demo app of Symfony, install Symfony with the following command:

```
symfony demo
```

You will then get the demo application described here: http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-demo-application

Comment: @Tiger Unfortunately the Symfony 2.7.0 "Getting started" pages are not already updated for the moment, but this should be alright soon.